# Add trigger to Jenkins pipeline

Tags: linux, jenkins, groovy, continuous-integration, devops

I want to add this trigger : "GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling" to my pipeline. Do anybody know how can i do it ? I've tried to find in offical documentation but no success.

Comment: Just searching with your quoted expression "GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling" takes me to [this result](https://oncomputingwell.princeton.edu/2018/01/triggering-a-jenkins-build-every-time-changes-are-pushed-to-a-git-branch-on-github/).

Answer (score 0):

GitHub hook triggers are not yet supported by the Pipeline syntax.

The official [documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#triggers) says:

> For Pipelines which are integrated with a source such as GitHub or BitBucket, triggers may not be necessary as webhooks-based integration will likely already be present. The triggers currently available are `cron`, `pollSCM` and `upstream`.

So, enabling it through the job configuration page from the Jenkins UI is currently the way to go.